# Bypass .htaccess authorization for specific URI including query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, authorization

I have a PHP web app that loads based on various query strings. I need the app to require authentication UNLESS a specific query string is passed.

For example, if the URL is example.com/app/?Setting1=true
I want to force authentication.

However, if the URL is example.com/app/?Setting1=true&Setting2=true
I want to bypass authentication

I am close to what I want using SetEnvIf Request_URI, but i'm not sure how to include query string vars into the Request_URI.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/app/test)$" allow

Order Deny,Allow

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home/path/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null

#Allow valid-user
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

I want something like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/app/?Setting1=true&Setting2=true)$" allow

Order Deny,Allow

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home/path/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null

#Allow valid-user
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" allow=0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:.*[&?])?Setting1=true&Setting2=true$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=allow:1]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:.*[&?])?Setting2=true&Setting1=true$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=allow:1]
<If "%{ENV:allow} == '0'">
        AuthUserFile /home/path/.htpasswd
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Access"
        Require user valid-user
</If>
```

Note:

- **SetEnvIf** does not support query string parameter. Please refer the below link.

[mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)

Its also possible to set environment variable using mod_rewrite module:

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags)